# Get current user's info from Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I am building a Twitter app (with oAuth) and I cannot find any info on how I can get the current user's info.

By current user, I mean the user which granted my app permissions and for whom the app is making the requests to the API.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It was actually "account/verify_credentials" as seen here:

> https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials.html

Comment: Link is to old v1 docs. New (v1.1) docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: If your app is not approved, set optional parameter `include_email` to false https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials otherwise you will get `Your credentials do not allow access to this resource` error.

Comment: I think the link is outdated again. It seems that the new URL is https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials.html

Comment: How to get user info in an android app from this link? I integrated twitter login but didn't find how to get user info afterwards. Should I parse the JSON data in my app?

Comment: The name is not very descriptive. That's why it's harder than necessary to find this :)

Answer (score 4):

Link to the documentation for API v. 1.1: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials

Answer (score 2):

Using oAuth you are able to make calls to get user info from your TwitterOAuth object.

**e.g if**

```
$oauth = new TwitterOAuth([keys here]);

$credentials = $oauth->get('account/verify_credentials');

echo "Connected as @" . $credentials->screen_name ."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution respecting iOS:

1) If you have a Twitter account (i.e. `ACAccount` from `ACAccountStore`) on your device, the only thing you need is to attach it to SLRequest and get all the user info from the returned dictionary:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[params setObject:[Twitter sharedInstance].session.userID forKey:@"user_id"];
[params setObject:@"0" forKey:@"include_entities"];
[params setObject:@"1" forKey:@"skip_status"];
[params setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_email"];

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:url parameters:params];
[request setAccount:twitterAccount]; //one of the Twitter Acc
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    if (responseData) {
        NSDictionary *twitterData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];
        });

    }else {
        NSLog(@"Error while downloading Twitter user data: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

2) Otherwise - you need to send OAuth (X-Auth) user credentials. The easiest way is to use TWTROAuthSigning class to retrieve OAuth-params:

```
TWTROAuthSigning *oauthSigning =
                         [[TWTROAuthSigning alloc]
                          initWithAuthConfig:
                          [Twitter sharedInstance].authConfig
                          authSession:session];
                         NSDictionary *authHeaders =
                         [oauthSigning OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentials];
```

and than send the ordinary request attaching credentials as header fields:

```
  NSString *oauthParameters = authHeaders[@"X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization"];
                         NSString *urlString = authHeaders[@"X-Auth-Service-Provider"];
                         NSMutableURLRequest *request =
                         [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
                         request.allHTTPHeaderFields = @{@"Authorization":oauthParameters};
                         [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                         NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
                         [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data,NSError *error){
                              NSDictionary *twitterData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];
                         }];
```

If you support an old version of Twitter SDK or searching for more options I'd recommend to look at [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) lib

Comment: Can you please share code for fetch twitter followers list?
Currently its always return false when I I try to requestAccessToAccountsWithType

Comment: @Anjalijariwala Do you have any example for getting profile details of twitter account including emailID . I have used the package "react-native-login-twitter" for my react-native application. Authentication is successfull and I got authToken, authTokenSecret of the profile but email is empty. Is there any second call required to get more profile infos using authToken & authTokenSecret . If so please help .. Thank you :)