# getting twitter username with access token

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I've a php application and successfully create a function to save access tokens and secrets in the database. (It's about sending specific content to their profile)

I want to show them which twitter account they linked to my application. How can I get their twitter user with access token?

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128323/get-current-users-info-from-twitter-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get the access token Twitter also returns a screen_name and user_id variables. You can use those instead of making an additional request to `GET account/verify_credentials`

Comment: I checked class codes and returned values but I could not get screen name, just id is available.

I used users/lookup to get screen name..

$connection->get('users/lookup', array('user_id' => '###'))

thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$credentials = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials')
```

and then to get username, name, and location-

```
$name = $credentials->name;

$username = $credentials->screen_name;

$location = $credentials->location;
```